# Spinner data in Main Activity is lost after using camera for scanning a QR Code

Tags: java, android, android-layout, spinner, qr-code

Hi I am new to Android programming.

When the mainacitivity is loaded I can fetch the data from sql server and populate it in spinner. I can choose an item from spinner and scan the qrcode/ barcode. Once i stop the camera and return to the MainActivity, I can't find any data in the spinner. Please let me know if you need more info about the question. I have provided the whole code in MainActivity.java file.

```
 package com.example.vxt.barcodescanner;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;import android.widget.AdapterView;import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;import android.widget.Button;//import android.widget.ProgressBar;import android.widget.Spinner;import android.app.AlertDialog;import android.content.DialogInterface;import com.google.zxing.Result;import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;import java.sql.Connection;import java.sql.ResultSet;import java.sql.PreparedStatement;import java.util.ArrayList;import static com.example.vxt.barcodescanner.R.id.spinner;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    ConnectionClass connectionClass;
    //ProgressBar pbbar;
    Spinner spinnerProducts;
    private  ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    ArrayList<String> scanned_data = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    String productSelected;
    Button scan, pushToDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        //pbbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbbar);
        //pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spinnerProducts = (Spinner) findViewById(spinner);
        scan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        pushToDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con != null) {

                String query = "select * from Products";
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                data.add("<--- Select a Product --->");
                while(rs.next()){
                    String product = rs.getString("Product");
                    String id = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("Id"));
                    data.add(product + "----" + id);
                }

                ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
                spinnerProducts.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
                //pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scan.setEnabled(false);
                pushToDB.setEnabled(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        spinnerProducts.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(spinnerProducts.getSelectedItemPosition() != 0){
                    scan.setEnabled(true);
                }
                productSelected = spinnerProducts.getSelectedItem().toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) { /* do nothing */ }


    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(MainActivity.this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    public void onClickDB(View v){
        //pbbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        pushToDB.setEnabled(false);
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con != null) {
                String query, query1;
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement, preparedStatement1;  // = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs; // = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                String[] splArray;
                //SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorAdapter) spinnerProducts.getAdapter();
                for (int position = 1; position < scanned_data.size(); position++) {
                    splArray = scanned_data.get(position).split(",");
                    query = "select * from Products_Barcode where ProductId ='" + splArray[1] + "'";
                    preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()){
                        query1 = "Update Products_Barcode set Barcode = '" + splArray[2] + "' where ProductId = '" + splArray[1] + "'";
                        preparedStatement1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
                        preparedStatement1.executeQuery();
                    }
                    else{
                        query1 = "insert into Products_Barcode values ('" + splArray[1] + "','" + splArray[0] + "','" + splArray[2] + "');";
                        preparedStatement1 = con.prepareStatement(query1);
                        preparedStatement1.executeQuery();
                    }
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Data tranferred successfully")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }


    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        //if(chk == 0){
        Log.v("handleResult", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        String source_text = result.getText();
        String prod = productSelected.replace("----", ",");
        scanned_data.add(prod + "," + source_text);
        builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
        builder.setMessage("Scan complete")

                //chk = 1;
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        dialog.cancel();
                            /*chk = 1;
                            mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(MainActivity.this);*/
                    }
                });
        spinnerProducts.setSelection(0);
        scan.setEnabled(false);
        if(!pushToDB.isEnabled()){
            pushToDB.setEnabled(true);
        }
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //pbbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
        NoCoreAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProducts.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: can you try moving the SQL connection to a separate method and call it both from OnCreate and OnResume? my guess is that the spinner gets re-populated OnResume, but since no code is there it loses the data. I might be wrong as well.

Comment: @Phantomazi Thank you. I tried your idea of creating seperate method and calling it onCreate and onResume. The spinner at the start had two sets of data in it. But when I scan a barcode and come back to the activity_main, spinner is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the spinner data somewhere inside the `onPause` method.

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    Data data = spinner.getData(); //Implement your own logic
}
```

When You come back to the `MainActivity` your `onResume` method is called where you have to feed the data back to the spinner.

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    spinner.setData(data); //Implement your own logic
}
```

[EDIT]

The problem is, you are using the `setContentView()` multiple times which is a bad practice. According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)

> Set the activity content to an explicit view. This view is placed directly into the activity's view hierarchy.

If you want to achieve what you currently wish, you should use fragments.

In short, do not call the `setContentView()` multiple times. Use `fragment` to show multiple `xml` without changing the activity.

Comment: Made a mistake! Edited. Check the latest one.

Comment: I have modified to the code as you advised but I can't seem to get it working. Should be a silly mistake but couldn't find it. I have attched the modified code as a txt file. Could please go through it once and give me suggesstion. Thank you.   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1xgv6ovbMbWSXB5c2Q4UDltSHM

Comment: Try also calling `loadProducts()` from the `onResume` method. Remove your `loadProducts()` and `fillSpinner()` from `onCreate()` because when even when your activity runs for first time, `onResume()` is called.

Comment: I tried various combination of using the functions in loadProducts() and fillSpinners() in onCreate() and onResume(). As you said the products got loaded in the spinner during the app launch, once I scan a bar code and return to mainActivity the spinner data is empty

Comment: I discarded the data from db. I used a simple string array. I populated it onResume() and when I scan the barcode and setContentView to mainActivity. I cannot see any values being populated.

Comment: Are you using `setContentView` more than once? Or are you calling that in `onResume`? If you are doing that, do not do that.

Comment: Oh! I got the issue. You are calling `setContentView` multiple time because of which your main_activity.xml is being set multiple time clearing the spinner.

Comment: I initially had this doubt. But what I dont know is I have only one activity in my project (MainActivity.xml) https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-qr-code-scanner-using-zxingscanner-library-tutorial/  From this tutorial I used zxing library to read a QR Code. once the camera starts and I read the Qr Code value. I don't know how to return to MainActivity.xml. So I set the content view to MainActivity.xml which leads to data loss in the spinner.

Comment: I cant help with the library as I havent used that. You need to do a bit of research yourself. If you feel this answer is correct. You can mark it accepted.